# Hibernate Exception while executing query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

Following is my code snippet:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml");
            JpaTransactionManager jpatm = (JpaTransactionManager) ctx
                    .getBean("transactionManager");
            EntityManager em = jpatm.getEntityManagerFactory()
                    .createEntityManager();
String sqlQuery = "SELECT suc FROM SubUsrCont suc, UDMap uDMap WHERE suc.userid = uDMap.userid AND uDMap.parentuserid = :parentuserid";
TypedQuery<SubUsrCont> query = (TypedQuery<SubUsrCont>) em.createQuery(sqlQuery, SubUsrCont.class);
query.setParameter("parentuserid", parentid);
ArrayList<SubUsrCont> listContent = (ArrayList<SubUsrCont>) query.getResultList();
```

But when ever executed I get the following error:

```
[http-8080-1] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - line 1:92: expecting OPEN, found '.'
```

Can anybody help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found it and successfully tested it as well. It was due to my POJO package name. Previously it was **in.myproject.myname**. I changed it to **com.myproject.myname**. HQL was taking **in** as the SQL Keyword IN and was looking for **OPEN '('**.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a Native SQL query inside `em.createQuery()`? This will not work because HQL can not have `SELECT` and furthermore you don't set the value for parameter `:parentuserid`.

```
String sqlQuery = "FROM SubUsrCont suc, UDMap uDMap WHERE suc.userid = uDMap.userid AND uDMap.parentuserid = :parentuserid";
TypedQuery<SubUsrCont> query = (TypedQuery<SubUsrCont>) em.createQuery(sqlQuery, SubUsrCont.class);
query.setParameter("parentuserid", <PARENT USER ID TO BE SEARCHED>);
```

Try this and see

Comment: @shazin... It ain't working.... org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to execute SQL use `createNativeQuery`. Also try "SELECT suc.* ...

Also you don't set the parameter :parentuserid

Use `query setParameter("parentuserid",someValue)`

Comment: @StanislavL... Well it's not working. But I know what the problem is. I have used Spring Roo to generate the project. So the actual table name in the DB in the case of SubUsrCont POJO is sub_usr_cont. Now when I used createNativeQuery it is simply converting the SubUsrCont to subusrcont. Which actually doesn't exists in the DB. I get the following error: ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Table 'mydb.subusrcont' doesn't exist